# How to toggle `details` tag by custom button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React docs has a nice button to toggle details tag, see here https://react.dev/learn/thinking-in-react#props-vs-state

How is this done? I'd like to obtain similar effect, ideally without introducing `state`s. Here is my curent code but clicking on button does not toggle details tag and clicking on title toggle it while it shouldn't: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/details-lnjnds?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A15%2C1

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <details>
      <summary style={{ listStyleType: "none" }}>
        <h5>Title</h5>
        <button>Open</button>
      </summary>
      <div>Content</div>
    </details>
  );
}
```

Comment: I cannot access the codesandbox. Is it set to private? 

Comment: Just style [`details/summary` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details)? No state required.

Comment: @deEr. sorry added a code to the question

Comment: @deEr. and working sandbox https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/details-lnjnds?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A15%2C1

Comment: You can see source code of it [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react.dev/blob/156765fc763bb85a7a6dc5eb1bd155801bbebaee/src/components/MDX/ExpandableExample.tsx#L21) but they have used state to tack it. If you don't want to use `state` you can achieve this using CSS only with help of `input[type=checkbox]` and `<label>` only but its bit complex .